# Setting Page Scroll on "get_next_posts_link"?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I currently am developing a custom Wordpress theme.  The page is set up in a single page vertically scrolling format.  At one point in the theme there is a blogroll with the option to view older posts.  Clicking to view older posts refreshes the page & brings the user back to the top,  I want to user to remain in place so that upon clicking "View Older Posts" the posts are refreshed and the user is still at the same fixed scroll area instead of being bumped back to the top.

Is there a possible way to use Jquery to bring the next posts in? I thought about editing the "get_next_post_link" function in link-template.php but I'm not sure what javascript to use or how to modify the code to work:

```html
function get_next_post_link( $format = '%link &raquo;', $link = '%title', $in_same_term = false, $excluded_terms = '', $taxonomy = 'category' ) {
 return get_adjacent_post_link( $format, $link, $in_same_term, $excluded_terms, false, $taxonomy );
}
```

I am using a modified version of this theme:

http://www.andersnoren.se/themes/fukasawa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the system in the facebook or twitter. First, you should add a pointer div element. And when click **'page 2'** create query in new page template same as:

```
$page=$_GET['paged']; // page 2 to get param
$showposts=10;
$offset=($page-1)*$showposts;
query_posts('offset='.$offset.'&showposts='.$showposts);

while(have_posts()):
   the_post();
   // ...
endwhile;
```

And add button click event with jQuery:

```
$(".pagenavi li a").click(function(){
    var new_page = $(this).attr("href");

    $("#ajax-area").html("LOADING");
    $("#ajax-area").append(new_page);
return false;
});
```